# Limit of this integral: $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\int_x^{x^2}\sinh(t)\sin(t)\,dt}{\int_0^x t^3\csc(t)\,dt}$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, derivatives, definite-integrals

> $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\int_x^{x^2}\sinh(t)\sin(t)\,dt}{\int_0^x t^3\csc(t)\,dt}.$$

I'm not sure what to do for this I tried integrating both the numerator and denominator separately but I wasn't sure how to solve the denominator.

For the numerator I got:

$$\frac{1}{2}\left(-\cos(x^2)\sinh(x^2)+\sin(x^2)\cosh(x^2)+\cos(x)\sinh(x)-\sin(x)\cosh(x)\right)$$

Comment: use leibniz theorem [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Using L'Hospital rule and Fundamental thereom of calculus

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\int_x^{x^2}\sinh(t)\sin(t)\,\mathrm dt}{\int_0^{x}t^3\csc(t)\,\mathrm dt}
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\int_0^{x^2}\sinh(t)\sin(t)\,\mathrm dt-\int_0^{x}\sinh(t)\sin(t)\,\mathrm dt}{\int_0^{x}t^3\csc(t)\,\mathrm dt}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\int_0^{x^2}\sinh(t)\sin(t)\,\mathrm dt-\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\int_0^{x}\sinh(t)\sin(t)\,\mathrm dt}{\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\int_0^{x}t^3\csc(t)\,\mathrm dt}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2x\sinh(x^2)\sin(x^2)-\sinh(x)\sin(x)}{x^3\csc(x)}\\
\end{align}$$
I hope you can take it from here

Comment: I was wondering if it had something to do with L'H rule alright ill try it that way and see what I end up with thanks!

Comment: Alright so after I applied L'H Rule and applied the limit I got a result of -1, not sure if you did the math for the rest but since its a non zero result i'm assuming its correct.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\lim_{x\ \to\ 0}{\ds{\int_{x}^{x^{2}}\sinh\pars{t}\sin\pars{t}\,\dd t}\over
\ds{\int_{0}^{x}t^{3}\csc\pars{t}\,\dd t}}}
=\lim_{x\ \to\ 0}{\ds{\int_{x}^{x^{2}}t^{2}\,\dd t} \over \ds{\int_{0}^{x}t^{2}\,\dd t}}
=\lim_{x\ \to\ 0}{x^{6}/3 - x^{3}/3 \over x^{3}/3}
\\[5mm]&=\lim_{x\ \to\ 0}\pars{x^{3} - 1}=\color{#66f}{\large -1}
\end{align}

> In addition, there is another approach $\ds{\pars{~L'H\hat{o}pital's\ Rule~}}$:
>   \begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
> \lim_{x\ \to\ 0}{\ds{\int_{x}^{x^{2}}\sinh\pars{t}\sin\pars{t}\,\dd t}\over
> \ds{\int_{0}^{x}t^{3}\csc\pars{t}\,\dd t}}}
> \\[5mm]&=\lim_{x\ \to\ 0}{\ds{\int_{0}^{x^{2}}\sinh\pars{t}\sin\pars{t}\,\dd t
> -\int_{0}^{x}\sinh\pars{t}\sin\pars{t}\,\dd t}\over
> \ds{\int_{0}^{x}t^{3}\csc\pars{t}\,\dd t}}
> \\[5mm]&=\lim_{x\ \to\ 0}{\bracks{\sinh\pars{x^{2}}\sin\pars{x^{2}}}\pars{2x}
> -\sinh\pars{x}\sin\pars{x} \over x^{3}\csc\pars{x}}
> \\[5mm]&=\lim_{x\ \to\ 0}\braces{2\
> \underbrace{\sinh\pars{x^{2}} \over x^{2}}_{\ds{\color{#c00000}{\to\ 1}}}\
> \underbrace{\sin\pars{x^{2}}\sin\pars{x}}_{\ds{\color{#c00000}{\to\ 0}}}\ -\
> \underbrace{{\sinh\pars{x} \over x}}_{\ds{\color{#c00000}{\to\ 1}}}\
> \underbrace{\bracks{\sin\pars{x} \over x}^{2}}_{\ds{\color{#c00000}{\to\ 1}}}}
> =\color{#66f}{\large -1}
> \end{align}